# Axios not POSTing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, axios

I have a React app that sends data to my custom Flask API.

```
const params = {
            id: this.props.user.uid,
            title: movie.title,
            movie_id: parseInt(movie.id, 10),
            photo: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + movie.backdrop_path,
            year: parseInt(movie.release_date.split("-")[0], 10),
            rating: parseInt(parseFloat(movie.vote_average) * 10, 10),
            overview: movie.overview,
            genres: genres
        };
```

When I print out `params.genres` it show something like this `["Fantasy", "Comedy"]`.
But when I post it:
 `axios.post("http://localhost:5000/user", params).then((data) => {`
The payload is:
`{"id":"id","title":"The Watch","movie_id":80035,"photo":"urltoimage","year":2012,"rating":55,"overview":"overview","genres":[]}`

All of the value are correct except the genres. And in my backend it says the same.
What's wrong?

My whole function:

```
addMovie(movie) {
        //get more data from tmdb
        var genres = [];
        axios
            .get(
                "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" +
                    parseInt(movie.id, 10),
                {
                    params: {
                        api_key: "dontsteelmytmdbkey;)",
                    },
                }
            )
            .then((req) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < req.data.genres.length; i++){
                    genres.push(req.data.genres[i].name);
                }
            });
        console.log(genres);
        const params = {
            id: this.props.user.uid,
            title: movie.title,
            movie_id: parseInt(movie.id, 10),
            photo: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + movie.backdrop_path,
            year: parseInt(movie.release_date.split("-")[0], 10),
            rating: parseInt(parseFloat(movie.vote_average) * 10, 10),
            overview: movie.overview,
            genres: genres
        };
        console.log(params.genres);
        axios.post("http://localhost:5000/user", JSON.stringify(params)).then((data) => {
            if (data.data.code === 112) {
                // success alert
                console.log("success alert");
                // remove movie from list
                let newMovies = this.state.movies;
                for (let i = 0; i < newMovies.length; i++) {
                    if (newMovies[i].id === movie.id) {
                        newMovies.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
                this.setState({ movies: newMovies });
            } else {
                console.log("Backend error");
                console.log(
                    "Error: " + data.data.code + " - " + data.data.errno
                );
                this.setState({
                    showAlert: true,
                    alertSeverity: "error",
                    alertText: this.state.alertServerError,
                });
            }
        });

        // dont redirect
        //this.props.history.push("/");
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your whole code including genres array then I can take a look?

Comment: I uploaded my whole add function

Comment: Both the ``console.log(genres)`` and ``console.log(params.genres)`` are returning array of genres, as I said before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These axios calls are both async at the moment and they don't wait for each other to be settled.
Try modifying your code like this to wait for the first call to be resolved then then loop over the genres.

```js
// add async to function definition 
async function addMovie(movie) {
  // get more data from tmdb
  const genres = [];
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + parseInt(movie.id, 10), {
      params: {
        api_key: 'dontsteelmytmdbkey;)',
      },
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < response.data.genres.length; i++) {
      genres.push(response.data.genres[i].name);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
  console.log(genres);
  const params = {
    id: this.props.user.uid,
    title: movie.title,
    movie_id: parseInt(movie.id, 10),
    photo: 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/' + movie.backdrop_path,
    year: parseInt(movie.release_date.split('-')[0], 10),
    rating: parseInt(parseFloat(movie.vote_average) * 10, 10),
    overview: movie.overview,
    genres: genres,
  };
  console.log(params.genres);
  axios.post('http://localhost:5000/user', JSON.stringify(params)).then((data) => {
    if (data.data.code === 112) {
      // success alert
      console.log('success alert');
      // remove movie from list
      let newMovies = this.state.movies;
      for (let i = 0; i < newMovies.length; i++) {
        if (newMovies[i].id === movie.id) {
          newMovies.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
      this.setState({ movies: newMovies });
    } else {
      console.log('Backend error');
      console.log('Error: ' + data.data.code + ' - ' + data.data.errno);
      this.setState({
        showAlert: true,
        alertSeverity: 'error',
        alertText: this.state.alertServerError,
      });
    }
  });

  // dont redirect
  // this.props.history.push("/");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the try statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
var genres = [];
        const res = await axios
            .get(
                "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" +
                    parseInt(movie.id, 10),
                {
                    params: {
                        api_key: "dontsteelmytmdbkey;)",
                    },
                }
            )
            
            for (let i = 0; i < res.data.genres.length; i++){
                    genres.push(res.data.genres[i].name);
            }
```

Make your addMovie function asynchronous use async keyword before addMovie function.

why you need this? because you have to wait until axios response resolve.

for your better understanding you can read more about Async Await

Answer (score 0):

It's not waiting to execute the API call you should use async and await. I've added in below code:

```
addMovie(movie) async {
    //get more data from tmdb
    var genres = [];
    await axios
        .get(
            "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" +
                parseInt(movie.id, 10),
            {
                params: {
                    api_key: "dontsteelmytmdbkey;)",
                },
            }
        )
        .then((req) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < req.data.genres.length; i++){
                genres.push(req.data.genres[i].name);
            }
        });
    console.log(genres);
    const params = {
```

Comment: This is not the right way to wait for the request to be resolved
async should be before the function keyword
callback chaining and await doesn't work this way I guess
This answer shouldn't be marked as accepted one

Comment: i don't have privilage to edit or comment on your answer but your code will eventually break the code if the request is not processsed or due to server problem. you will need to add the api call in try catch block.